# How should I model my MongoDB collection for nested documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm managing a MongoDB database for a building products store. The most immediate collection is products, right?
There are quite several products, however they all belong to one among a set of 5-8 categories and then to one subcatefory among a small set of subcategories.

For example:

```
-Electrical
  *Wires
    p1
    p2
    ..
  *Tools
    p5
    pn
    ..
  *Sockets
    p11
    p23
    ..
-Plumber
  *Pipes
    ..
  *Tools
    ..
  PVC
    ..
```

I will use Angular at web site client side to show whole products catalog, I think about AJAX for querying the right subset of products I want.

Then, I wonder whether I should manage one only collection like:

```
{
    
    MainCategory1: {


        SubCategory1: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategory2: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategoryn: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }               
    },
    MainCategory2: {


        SubCategory1: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategory2: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategoryn: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }               
    },  
    MainCategoryn: {


        SubCategory1: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategory2: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }
        SubCategoryn: {
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{}
        }               
    }   
}
```

Or a single collection per each category. The number of documents might not be higher than 500. However I care about a balance for:

- quick DB answer,
- easy server side DB querying, and
- client-side Angular code for rendering results to html.

I'm using [mongodb node.js module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb), not Mongoose now.

#### **What CRUD operations will I do?**

- **Inserts of products**, I'd also like to have a way to obtain autogenerated ids (maybe sequential) per each new register. However, as it might seem natural I wouldn't offer the **_id** to the user.
- **Querying** the whole **documents set** of a subcategory. Maybe just obtaining a few attributes at first.
- **Querying** whole or a specific **subset of attributes of a document** (product) in particular.
- **Modifying** a product's **attributes** values.

Comment: What db query do you need? Mongodb is fast database for read data? if you use indexes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree client side should get the easiest result to render. However, to nest categories into products is still a bad idea. The trade off is once you want to change, for example, the name of a category, it will be a disaster. And if you think about the possible usecases, for example:

- list all categories
- find all subcategories of a certain category
- find all products in a certain category

You'll find it hard to do these stuff with your data structure.

I had same situation in my current project. So here's what I do for your reference.
First, categories should be in a separate collection. **DON'T** nest categories into each other, as it will complicate the procedure to find all subcategories. The traditional way for finding all subcategories is to maintain an `idPath` property. For example, your categories are divided into 3 levels:

```
{
    _id: 100,
    name: "level1 category"
    parentId: 0,  // means it's the top category
    idPath: "0-100"
}
{
    _id: 101,
    name: "level2 category"
    parentId: 100,
    idPath: "0-100-101"
}
{
    _id: 102,
    name: "level3 category"
    parentId: 101,
    idPath: "0-100-101-102"
}
```

Note with idPath, parentId is not necessary anymore. It's for you to understand the structure easier.
Once you need to find all subcategories of category 100, simply do the query:

```
db.collection("category").find({_id: /^0-100-/}, function(err, doc) {
    // whatever you want to do
})
```

With category stored in a separate collection, in your product you'll need to reference them by _id, just like when we use RDBMS. For example:

```
{
    ... // other fields of product
    categories: [100, 101, 102, ...]
}
```

Now if you want to find all products in a certain category:

```
db.collection("category").find({_id: new RegExp("/^" + idPath + "-/"}, function(err, categories) {
    var cateIds = _.pluck(categories, "_id"); // I'm using underscore to pluck category ids
    db.collection("product").find({categories: { $in: cateIds }}, function(err, products) {
        // products are here
    }
})
```

Fortunately, category collection is usually very small, with only hundreds of records inside (or thousands). And it doesn't varies a lot. So you can always store a live copy of categories inside memory, and it can be constructed as nested objects like:

```
[{
    id: 100,
    name: "level 1 category",
    ... // other fields
    subcategories: [{
        id: 101,
        ... // other fields
        subcategories: [...]
    }, {
        id: 103,
        ... // other fields
        subcategories: [...]
    },
    ...]
}, {
    // another top1 category
}, ...]
```

You may want to refresh this copy every several hours, so:

```
setTimeout(3600000, function() {
    // refresh your memory copy of categories.
});
```

That's all I get in mind right now. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

- to provide int ID for each user, [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and [findAndModify](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify) is very useful. you may have a idSeed collection:

  ```
  {
      _id: ...,
      seedValue: 1,
      forCollection: "user"
  }
  ```

  When you want to get an unique ID:

  ```
  db.collection("idSeed").findAndModify({forCollection: "user"}, {}, {$inc: {seedValue: 1}}, {}, function(err, doc) {
      var newId = doc.seedValue;
  });
  ```

  The findAndModify is an atomic operator provided by mongodb. It will guarantee thread safety. and the find and modify actually happens in a "transaction".
- 2nd question is in my answer already.
- query subsets of properties is described with [mongodb Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). NodeJS API is almost the same. Read the document of `projection` parameter.
- update subsets is also supported by [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) of mongodb operator.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really reading it and following it. Can you check my last edits? I mention what CRUD I will do, also about codes generation for each register.

Comment: I edit my answer. The 1st question is kind of tricky so I showed how to do it. the following 3 questions are just regular mongodb operations, So I just leave to documents for you to read.

Comment: Thanks! Why, in the function pass `{$inc: {seedValue: 1}}` as parameter? As I understand I will create at first a dummy collection with seed values (maybe all 1s). Then before inserting I will get next id (already incremented)?

Comment: the operator $inc increases the seedValue by 1 if that's what you are asking. And the value before updating is returned in the callback. Thus each time you invoke this code, it will give you a unique int ID.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: I can always receive via ajax the whole document, including `_id` but when querying for each again, I can associate the `ID` with `_id` and querying by last, right? :)

I'm a newbie with Mongo, I like it and use it now because love JS Obecjts/JSON and SQL eats bunches of RAM ...

Comment: Remember _id doesn't have to be ObjectId, it can be anything you want, as long as it's unique. So it OK if you assigned the int ID to _id field. It will simplify your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54259/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-yaoxing).