# Mongodb - hierarchy path query

Tags: mongodb

Given the following collection in mongoDb,  I would like to give the user the location in the tree (concatenate the path to the root) as:
**Root.Application.Config.Timeouts**
Is there an easy way to do this in mongoDb, or I will have to use the find method with the parentHierarchyId recursively until its null?

```
{
  "hierarchyId" : 0,
  "parentHierarchyId" : null,
  "hierarchyName" : "Root",
}
{
  "hierarchyId" : 1,
  "parentHierarchyId" : 0,
  "hierarchyName" : "Application",
}
{
  "hierarchyId" : 2,
  "parentHierarchyId" : 1,
  "hierarchyName" : "Config",
}
{
  "hierarchyId" : 3,
  "parentHierarchyId" : 2,
  "hierarchyName" : "Timeouts",
}
```

Comment: so if you have 1000 records you just need to get the Hierarchy field and concatenate it into a single field? AFAIK there is nothing out of the box for this in MongoDB. But if you use aggregation you should be able to get all the values in a single array or something. I can check that query if thats what you are looking for?

Comment: You might want to have a look at ["Model Tree Structures" in the MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)

Comment: The tree will never get to 1000 deep, maximum is like 10

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a classic question. It's not only about MongoDB but also for RDBMS. Answered it once in another form. See if it answers your question:

[How should I model my MongoDB collection for nested documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821786/how-should-i-model-my-mongodb-collection-for-nested-documents/23822437#23822437)